# SEO: Use #hash link in HREF or use a normal link for AJAX links?

Tags: ajax, seo

My site relies heavily on AJAX. I'm using `#!` in URLs to maintain back button functionality and a different URL for each page.

This is how my links look right now:

```
<a href="#!/something">
```

I'm considering this other approach, so that my links have regular hrefs:

```
<a href="/something" class="ajax">

$("a.ajax").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location = '/#!' + $(this).attr('href');
    });
```

The advantage would be that all pages would already have an http address and I'm considering doing a non-js version of the site so it would be easier to do it.

Anyway I don't know what to choose, are there advantages (with SEO or others) on one over the other?

Comment: Check out pushState as another option to eliminate the #!

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see there is no problem with

```
<a href="#!/something">
```

You can go through this [Google FAQ on Ajax Crawling](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/faq)

Also go through this [Ajax Crawling Getting Started Guide by Google](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/getting-started)

Lastly, don't forget to update your Sitemap to list the new AJAX URLs..